# check status of pointer -events using jquery

Tags: jquery, pointer-events

Is it possible to check the status of pointer events within a class. I want to know if the pointer-events within a class is hidden or visible. I tried :

```
var a =  $(".overlay").pointerEvents();
```

but it seems it is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the value of a css property for a DOM element, you need to use the css method:

```
var a =  $(".overlay").css('pointer-events');
```